# Nesting and / or conditions with Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, nested

this is my first post here. I'm taking my first steps with Parse.com and now I am stuck with a problem I have not been able to solve. 
Previous to asking I have been searching for a solution but I have found nothing.

The fact is that I have to retrieve the records from a table according to the values of two different columns.

Let's consider the following table:

```
idSection   idItem
---------   ------
1             10 
1             11
1             12
2             20
2             21
2             22
2             23
3             31
3             32
3             33
```

What I need is to create a select of 'and' / 'or' conditions in the following way:

```
select *
from table1
where (idSection = 1 and idItem > 11)
   or (idSection = 2 and idItem > 22)
   or (idSection = 3 and idItem > 32)
```

Any ideas?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'd have to do 3 separate queries. A CloudCode function is probably the best route to go.

Comment: are you working in javascript or mobile?

Comment: Performing 3 different queries was the first thought, but I there had to be a better aproach. Further more, it wouldn't be "elegant" and as I use a free account of Parse, I have a limit in the number of requests. ccwasden answer worked fine. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in iOS, you can do this:

```
NSPredicate * pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(idSection = 1 and idItem > 11) or (idSection = 2 and idItem > 22) or (idSection = 3 and idItem > 32)"];
PFQuery * q = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyClass" predicate:pred];
[q findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"OBJ : %@",objects);
}];
```

If javascript, do this:

```
var clz = "MyClass";

var q1 = new Parse.Query(clz);
q1.equalTo("idSection", 1);
q1.greaterThan("idItem", 11);

var q2 = new Parse.Query(clz);
q2.equalTo("idSection", 2);
q2.greaterThan("idItem", 22);

var q3 = new Parse.Query(clz);
q3.equalTo("idSection", 3);
q3.greaterThan("idItem", 32);

var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(q1,q2,q3);
mainQuery.find({
  success: function(results) {

  },
  error: function(error) {

  }
});
```

Android is similar to javascript.. see the "or" method in ParseQuery class here https://parse.com/docs/android/api/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I swear I searched the web before asking, and the first place I looked into was the api of Parse, and I did not find the "or" function. I had seen it used in javascript, just as you did, but was not able to see it for android. I will try it this afternoon.